# Postgresql: Get columns of other table as array in a object as a column with condition

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

i have 2 tables, servers and virtual_machines. I want to see the virtual_machines as array in the servers where serverName equals the servers name

Like this

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID | Name    | virtual_machines                                    
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1 | Server1 | [{id:1,name:'vm1',serverName:'Server1'},{id:2,name:'vm2',serverName:'Server1'}]
```

I have servers tables

```
+-------------------------------------+
|ID | Name | 
+-------------------------------------+
```

and virtual_machines tables

```
+-------------------------------------+
|ID | Name | serverName
+-------------------------------------+
```

I tried many options like bellow but i cant make object array in colum and postgre always add key into object.

```sql
SELECT srv.*
     , json_build_object('VM', vm.*)
FROM servers srv, virtual_machines vm WHERE vm.serverName = srv.Name
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_agg()` to have both the virtual_machines in one row.

```
SELECT srv.id,srv.name
     ,array_agg( json_build_object('VM', vm.*))
FROM servers srv, virtual_machines vm WHERE vm.serverName = srv.Name
group by srv.id,srv.name



 create table servers(ID int, Name varchar(50));
 
 create table virtual_machines (ID int, Name varchar(50), serverName varchar(50));

 
 insert into servers values( 1 , 'Server1');
 insert into virtual_machines values(1,'vm1','Server1');
 insert into virtual_machines values(2,'vm2','Server1');
```

Query:

```
 SELECT srv.id,srv.name
      ,jsonb_agg    ( json_build_object('id', vm.id, 'name', vm.name, 'serverName', vm.serverName))virtual_machines
 FROM servers srv, virtual_machines vm WHERE vm.serverName = srv.Name
 group by srv.id,srv.name
```

Output:

| id | name | virtual_machines |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Server1 | [{id: 2, name: vm2, serverName: Server1}, {id: 1, name: vm1, serverName: Server1}] |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ef341d17ae4addecbf02fdd6d097e03d)*

With `services` table :

```
 create table servers(ID int, Name varchar(50));
 
 create table virtual_machines (ID int, Name varchar(50), serverName varchar(50));
 create table Services (ID int, Name varchar(50), vmName varchar(50));
 
 insert into servers values( 1 , 'Server1');
 insert into virtual_machines values(1,'vm1','Server1');
 insert into virtual_machines values(2,'vm2','Server1');
 
 insert into Services values(1,'service1','vm1');
```

Query:

```
 with vm_services as
 (
     SELECT vm.id,vm.name, vm.servername
          ,jsonb_agg    ( json_build_object('id', s.id, 'name', s.name, 'vmName', s.vmname))Services
     FROM virtual_machines vm left join services s on vm.name = s.vmname
     group by vm.id,vm.name,vm.servername
     order by vm.id
 )
 SELECT srv.id,srv.name
      ,jsonb_agg    ( json_build_object('id', vm.id, 'name', vm.name, 'serverName', vm.serverName,'Services',vm.services))virtual_machines
 FROM servers srv inner join vm_services vm on vm.serverName = srv.Name
 group by srv.id,srv.name
```

Output:

| id | name | virtual_machines |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Server1 | [{id: 2, name: vm2, Services: [{id: null, name: null, vmName: null}], serverName: Server1}, {id: 1, name: vm1, Services: [{id: 1, name: service1, vmName: vm1}], serverName: Server1}] |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2a40eae8aa6bbd3d16c3eb62f7ab1894)*

Comment: thanks for answer, but what if i have one more table that calls "services" and i want to see them inside of virtual_machines like 
`[{id:1,name:'vm1',serverName:'Server1',services: [{id:1, name:'service1', vmName:'vm1'}]},{id:2,name:'vm2',serverName:'Server1'}]  `
i tried nested calls but postgre gave me this error 
`ERROR:  aggregate function calls cannot be nested`

Comment: You need to use cte or sub query. Will try to revise my answer in couple of hours.

Comment: I have revised my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thank you very much, i didnt know sub query thing sorry for that

Comment: You are most welcome. We are learning every day. Best wishes.